# How to enable using arrows keys to move row selection in JTable?

Tags: java, jtable, arrow-keys

I noticed that I can you arrows to move row selection of my JTable object only when I press tab key. Is it possible to use arrows after row selection by mouse-click (instead of using TAB)?

Comment: Can you post a relevant piece of code?  Are you sure your table is in focus when you are trying to traverse?

Comment: A table can gain focus either by tabbing from one component to the table or by clicking on a cell in the table. Once the table has focus the arrow keys will work. So I don't understand why you say it doesn't work after a mouse click. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the arrow keys to change row selection, the JTable must have focus. Pressing the `tab` key changes focus to the next (or first) "focussable" Component on the page which is likely a SubComponent in the JTable.

To get it to focus automatically when it becomes visible, add a [ComponentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/index.html) with the  an `componentShown(...)` method implemented to call the JTable's [`requestFocusInWindow()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow()) method.

> Is it possible to use arrows after row selection by mouse-click (instead of using TAB)

Yes; if you click the mouse on a row, that should also focus the row, allowing you to use the arrow keys as well.

**Updated**: corrected method used to get input focus, with thanks to [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) (see comments)

Comment: JTable object doesn't have getFocus() method. When I click on a row I can't use the arrow keys. I can use them only if I press TAB

Comment: @latata oops, I corrected the method name (and linked to javadoc) - use requestFocus().  If I run http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components/SimpleTableDemo.java and click any row in the table, I get the expected results: namely the arrow keys will work to change selected row, once a cell has been focused. Are you configuring the JTable with any non-default settings after you create it?

Comment: reqestFocus() is NOT the proper method to use. Please read the API for that method where it is suggested you use requestFocusInWindow().

Comment: @camickr thanks for the catch - it's been a while (pre jdk-1.4 apparently) since I've played with focus issues.